# CSS for Formatting Academic Publications APA Style

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a way to format a list of academic papers for a page I'm updating. I would like to make a CSS rule to format published articles like so:

[image: APA Citation]

I would like to do this automatically as entering `&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;` manually would be a waste of energy. Can CSS detect line breaks without `</p>` tags? Has anyone had luck with formatting like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The `text-indent` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent) adjusts the indentation of the first line. Set it to a negative value.

```css
p {
  text-indent: -2em;
  margin-left: 2em;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```